# My program is behaving in an unusual manner?

Tags: python

### THIS IS THE CODE:

```
import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

def miniMaxSum(arr):
    arr_min = arr
    arr_max = arr
    for x in range(len(arr_min)):
        if arr_min[x] == max(arr):
            print(max(arr))
            arr_min[x] = 0
            break
    for x in range(len(arr_max)):
        if arr_max[x] == min(arr_max):
            print(min(arr_max))
            arr_max[x] = 0
            break
    print(str(sum(arr_min))+" "+str(sum(arr_max)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
    miniMaxSum(arr)
```

**If my input array is [1,2,3,4,5] min(arr_max) giving me value 0.** Can anyone plese help me out. I can't understand why my program is behaving in this particular.

Comment: Double check your data. My guess is this has to do with the `arr_min = arr; arr_max = arr` lines at the top. Change those to `arr_min = arr[:]; arr_max = arr[:]` to make copies of `arr`. You're changing `arr`, `arr_min` and `arr_max` all at the same time right now, which I'm guessing isn't your intent.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thank you! This worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because you assigned both of the `arr_min` and `arr_max`  to refer to `arr` so when you are doing `arr_min[x] = 0` it's reflecting `arr_max[0]` to be 0 since both of them are shallow copies of the same arrays.
You can do

```
arr_min = arr[:]
arr_max = arr[:]
```

or use other types of copy like a deep copy when you initializing the `arr_min` and `arr_max` arrays to avoid such a problem.